# PHPPowerPoint Read file

Tags: php

Как прочитать .ppt файл используя библиотеку PHPPowerPoint?

Comment: возможно никак, ведь ppt это двоичный, а не openxml (для которого и предназначена PHPPowerPoint в первую очередь)

Comment: А как тогда можно прочитать ppt/pptx?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать [PHPPresentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation).

```
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory;

$pptFile   = '/path/to/file.ppt';
$pptReader = IOFactory::createReader('PowerPoint97');

$presentation = $pptReader->load($pptFile);

foreach ($presentation->getAllSlides() as $slide) {
    foreach ($slide->getShapeCollection() as $shape) {
        var_dump($shape);
    }
}
```

Более детально, как разобрать объект shape, смотрите [тут](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/blob/develop/samples/Sample_Header.php#L314).

Comment: Скачал архив, папку PhpPresentation-develop извлек в корень каталога, создал файл index.php вставил содержимое Вашего кода. Выводит ошибку Fatal error: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5

Comment: Почитайте внимательно документацию, там написано как правильно ее использовать.